# Copy whole row excluding identifier column

Tags: sql-server, copy

I'm trying to insert a new row into a table which is an exact copy of another row except for the identifier. Previously I hadn't had the issue because there was an ID-column which didn't fill automatically. So I could just copy a row like this

```sql
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Id = 5
```

And then manually change the ID like this

```sql
WITH tbl AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) AS RNr, Id
FROM table1 WHERE Id = 5 
UPDATE tbl SET Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM table1) + 1 
WHERE RNr = 2
```

Recently the column Id has changed to not be filled manually (which I also like better). But this leads to the error that I obviously can't fill that column while `IDENTITY_INSERT` is false. Unfortunately, I don't have the right to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT IdentityTable ON/OFF` before and after the statement, which I also would like to avoid anyways.

I'm looking for a way to insert the whole row excluding the Id column without naming each other column in the `INSERT` and `SELECT` statement (which are quite a lot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a way by using a temporary table

```
SELECT * INTO #TmpTbl
FROM table1 WHERE Id = 5;
ALTER TABLE #TmpTbl
DROP COLUMN Id;
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM #TmpTbl;
DROP TABLE #TmpTbl
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But lazy habits like this will only create more work in the long term. The best practice is to always specify the column list of an insert statement and to always specify the column list in a select statement. Only select the columns you need.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below the maximum value of the ID gets added by one, so your integrity is not violated.

```
insert into table1 
select a.Top_ID, Column2, Column3, ColumnX 
from table1 t1
outer apply (select max(id_column) + 1as Top_ID from table1) as a 
where t1.Id = 1
```

Comment: Hello Max, thank you. But my problem was that the ID column can't be filled automatically so it has to be left out. I found a way now which I have posted as an answer.